# Thermal control

Tags: thermal, thermal-control

I am interested in spacecraft thermal control. Is there any book on the subject with a good theoretical base that I could look into? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried gilmore’s spacecraft thermal control handbook?

Comment: I don't know if what you need can be found in answers at this [meta community wiki](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102) but you might take a look.

Comment: Also, here are some questions who's answers you might find interesting: 1.
 [How does a thermal control system of a spacecraft basicaly work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19888/12102), 2. [With one out of two Thermal Control Systems on ISS malfunctioning, how long can Loop B keep up with increased load?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3116/12102), 3. [What's the typical temperature of a satellite orbiting the Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7827/12102)

Comment: ...and definitely come back here if you have *specific questions* once you've started reading!

Comment: @Paul I didn't because I thought Gilmore talks about technologies and not the theory behind. Thanks! I'll take a look.

Comment: @uhoh Thank you, there are a lot of useful books! I'll come back definitely

Answer (score 2):

The [Spacecraft Thermal Control Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188498911X) by Gilmore is basically the go-to. [Volume 1](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.989117) focuses on thermal control in general, and [volume 2](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.989148) is specific for cryogenics.